# Why does Eclipse CPU usage increase when I run an application?

Tags: eclipse, jvm, cpu-usage, taskmanager

I run my Java application in Eclipse and see these two thing in Task Manager:

[image: task manager - what eclipse does?]

Before I start my application, Eclipse uses ~0% CPU. What exactly does Eclipse do after my program started?

If I run my application without Eclipse, will there be any difference in my Java process CPU usage in the case that my JVM settings are the same with Eclipse?

Comment: Eclipse has to read your program output to display it in the console, for example, which can take a bit of resource. So your application running outside Eclipse may go a bit faster.

Comment: If you are sure please make it an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Eclipse has to read your program output to display it in the console, for example, which can take a bit of resources, especially if your program generates lots of output and/or long lines of output (in my experience, the Eclipse console is quite slow). I suppose you're not running in debug mode, in which case Eclipse would have to do more to handle the debugging.

So your application running outside Eclipse may go a bit faster, yes.

You can of course run something like jvisualvm to get a thread dump of Eclipse while your program is running to find out exactly Eclipse is doing.